# Search more than one item in Gvim

Tags: search, vim, keyword

Is there an easy way in Gvim to search for more than one search item in a file simultaneously ? i.e I want Gvim to highlight Word1 and Word2 in a given file or RegExp1 and RegExp2 in a given file at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "or" regex operator: `/Word1\|Word2`